# Detect if user will leave body and show a dialog like Bounce Exchange

Tags: jquery

I was writing a jquery script to detect user if the leave the html body and going to close the website to show them a dialog box such as bounce exchange.

```
$('#bounce').fadeIn(300);
var popMargTop = ($('#bounce').height() + 24) / 2;
var popMargLeft = ($('#bounce').width() + 24) / 2;

$('#bounce').css({
    'margin-top': -popMargTop,
    'margin-left': -popMargLeft
});

// Add the mask to body
$('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
$('#mask').fadeIn(300);

// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('a.close, #mask').on('click', function () {
    $('#mask , .bounce-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $('#mask').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4NWH4/24/)
This example display a dialog on load event, how can i push this for mouse leave event(one time only)? like below code

```
$("body").one('mouseleave', function() {
    jQuery('#bounce').show();
});
```

Comment: You can't. You can only show a confirm type box.

Comment: there is nothing, developer can't. Because bounce exchange already done this.

Comment: Than your question doesn't make sense. You want to detect when a user leaves your website? E.g. close browser or go to another url right?

Comment: I want to show a dialog, when he is going to leave the body. $("body").one('mouseleave', function() {
    alert("you are leaving body");
});

Comment: @user1610100, site and body are two **very** different things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that if it fits your needs:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4NWH4/30/)

```
$(document).one('mouseleave', showDialog);
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, as you have done. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P9jNb/

```
var bounceBoxShown = false;

$('.btn-sign').mouseleave(function() {          
    if (bounceBoxShown) {
        return;
    }
    bounceBoxShown = true;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Moritz, I did little change and here is updated : http://fiddle.jshell.net/P9jNb/3/show/light/ to see, Can we also add cookie or something to show dialog one time only to a user visiting across pages and expire the cookie after n days or hours ?

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/4NWH4/32/ (using [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)).